# Pattern binding: why are recursive patterns allowed?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
Prelude> let (Just x) = Just (x - 1) in x
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

Why does the compiler accept that decl? It can tell syntactically it's bound to loop(?)

GHC sorta knows:

```
Prelude> :set -XBangPatterns
Prelude> let !(Just x) = Just (x - 1) in x
    Recursive bang-pattern or unboxed-tuple bindings aren't allowed:
```

[That `Exception` and compiler fail message at GHCi 7.10.2. At GHC 8.10 there's no helpful message, just looping.]

Is there some sensible use for recursive pattern-bindings? I think that for a pattern-binding decl, the free vars of the lhs should be disjoint from the free vars of the rhs(?)

By 'pattern-binding' I mean, per Haskell Language Report 2010, section 4.4.3.2, specifically a lhs starting with a data constructor/at outermost scope.

(I'm hoping for something more exciting than a bare single var on lhs. That still counts as a 'pattern-binding', see comments.)

Of course for function decls, the compiler has to allow recursion, because it can't tell syntactically if the function will loop:

```
Prelude> let { f 0 = 0;
               f x = f (x - 1) }           -- will terminate (for positive inputs)
             in f 5
```

Bare vars on lhs seem to me more like niladic functions than actual patterns.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your GHC error about recursive pattern bindings with GHC 9.0.1, on my machine GHCi gets stuck in an infinite loop (not even the <<loop>> exception) in both cases. Which GHC version are you using?

Comment: Ah ok. The `Exception <<loop>>` and `Recursive Bang-pattern` rejection are in GHC 7.10.3.  Yes GHC 8.10.2 just loops with no message in either case.

Comment: `let (Just x) = Just (1:x) in take 10 x` works perfectly fine. bang is seq, so only forces to WHNF which is already apparent here anyway, so there's no reason why it should be rejected.

Comment: *"A bare single var is still a 'Function binding' -- that is, a niladic function."* no, not so. it says right there `x p11 ... p1k match1 ....` i.e. `k >= 1`. so `x = ...` falls under pattern binding -- `x` being an irrefutable pattern `x`. and **4.4.3.2 Pattern bindings** starts with *"A simple pattern binding has form p  =  e. The pattern p is matched “lazily” as an irrefutable pattern, as if there were an implicit ~ in front of it."*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an example of useful code that uses recursive patterns with constructors and not just a single variable, see this breadth first relabeling function:

```hs
data Tree a
  = Leaf a
  | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving Show

bfl :: forall a b. [b] -> Tree a -> Tree b
bfl l t = result
  where
    go :: Tree a -> [[b]] -> ([[b]], Tree b)
    go (Node l r) (xs:xss0) = 
      let (xss1, l') = go l xss0
          (xss2, r') = go r xss1
      in (xs:xss2, Node l' r')
    go (Leaf _) ((x:xs):xss) = (xs:xss, Leaf x)
    (xss, result) = go t (l:xss)
```

Here on the very last line we use a tuple `(xss, result)` that is defined by passing `xss` itself to the `go` helper function. That is necessary to pass the resulting list of each level of the tree to the next level.

Comment: mmmm sweet code, thank you. Yes `go` needs to pass a data structure, because it's walking both the `Node`s and the input list supplying new values for `Leaf`s, taken in breadth-first sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Data can be just as lazy as functions in Haskell. As a result there are certainly use cases for recursive bindings. For example, consider this definition of `fix`:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x

twoOnes :: [Int]
twoOnes = take 2 $ fix (1 :)
```

Observe that since the right-hand side of the let-binding is non-strict in the left-hand side, the binding can produce results.

Even your original, "obviously silly" expression may terminate, given some equally silly `Num` instances:

```
instance Num () where
  fromInteger x = ()
  x - y = ()

loop :: ()
loop = let (Just x) = Just (x - 1) in x
```

Obviously not super useful for this specific type, but GHC is not in the business of deciding which legal expressions are useful, and with more work it's possible to imagine more useful Num instances that might terminate here.

Comment: From the O.P.: "for function decls, the compiler has to allow recursion". Then your `fix` example is not an answer to the question. Also from the O.P. "Is there some sensible use ...?", and you've given me an 'equally silly' `Num` instance.

Comment: The `fix` function is not recursive. Only the let-binding inside of it, a non-function, is. Also you are being weirdly aggressive, in your comment on my answer but especially on Carsten's deleted answer (which *also* featured a recursive non-function, `fibs`). Consider being more polite to get better results when asking for help.

Comment: @AntC For more "sensible" uses see [an old blog post of mine](http://noughtmare.gitlab.io/posts/2017-08-30-an-example-of-using-laziness.html) or [my implementation of the subset sum problem with lazy arrays](https://github.com/lehins/massiv/issues/111#issuecomment-753610109).

Comment: Thank you amalloy, @Noughtmare. I added to the q a definition of 'pattern-binding' from the Report. AFAICT the only pattern-binding is in the 'silly' `Num` example. In the `fix` example, `x` has a Function binding. Likewise `res` has a Function binding in the `solve coins` example. Note that `let x = 5` counts as a Function binding.

Comment: @AntC You are misreading the Report. The "function binding" has 1 or more arguments, not 0. And `x` is a pattern, of the simplest sort, so `let x = 5` is a pattern binding, not a function binding. There's no such thing as a niladic function.

Comment: Formally, a single variable pattern follows the `pat -> lpat -> apat -> var` production from the grammar in section 3.17.1.

Comment: @AntC I gave the relevant quotes in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733530/pattern-binding-why-are-recursive-patterns-allowed#comment119736235_67733530) under the Q. `p = e` is a _pattern_ binding; `let x = f x` is a _pattern_ binding for the irrefutable pattern `x`, just like @ amalloy is saying above. the binding for `fibs` in Carsten's answer is a _pattern_ binding so your comment there was factually wrong. as for the "patronizing", we really have no way of knowing the asker's level of understanding of various aspects of Haskell and besides, the readership is wider than 1.

Comment: @AntC wider than just 1 (the asker), so it wasn't patronizing at all. :)